# Handshake Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction

At a conference there are 2016 participants, numbered 1 to 2016. Each participant 1 through 2015 shook hands with as many people as his number. How many hands did the 2016th participant shake?

Comment: In that question it is possible for someone to have 0 friends.

Comment: Is it possible for someone to have *0* hands? A conference of amputees, maybe?  :)

Comment: The solution to this puzzle follows from the solution to the {0,1...13} situation in the other puzzle; you just have to ignore the first person.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE, take a tour here https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour to earn a badge! :D

Comment: I believe this leads to a different method of solution and significantly different answer than the 'Tiffany' question. So while @Apep correctly points out that 'you just have to ignore the first person', it's not immediately obvious how that will affect the answer. I won't put my answer here because I can't spoiler tag it.

Comment: OK since this question is dead in the water anyway... how about this: 1. Person 1 shakes hands with 2. 2 shakes with 1 and 3. 3 with 1,2 and 4. Proceed until 2015 shakes with 1 through 2014 plus 2016. So the answer is just 1. And if there had been 1000 000 people it would still be 1. A natural problem for proof by induction.

Comment: Each participant 1 through 2015 shook hands, no mention of the 2016th person shaking hands, so 2016th could of shook 0 hands or up to 2015 hands. so there is no definitive answer.  If the puzzle had stated: 'Only' participants 1 through 2015 shook hands then the answer would be 0.

Comment: @5202456 2016th could have shook 0 hands or up to 2015 hands, true, but given the information that 2015 shook hands with 2015 other people, we know that 2016 shook hands with 2015th (so at least 1). So the mention of participants 1 to 2015 shaking hands does give information about how many handshakes 2016 did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I didn't look at the possibly duplicate one and here's an answer:

> 2015 shakes hands with everyone (because there's only 2105 other people)
>  1 only shakes hands with 2015 (because that's one person already)
>  2014 shakes hands with everyone except 1 (only that many people left)
>  2 only shakes hands with 2015 and 2014 (that's two people already)
>  ... and so on
>  1009 shakes hands with everyone from 1007 upwards
>  1007 shakes hands with everyone from 1009 to 2015 (inclusive)
>  1008 shakes hands with everyone from 1009 to 2016
>
>  So, 2016 shakes 1008 people's hands (specifically the people numbered 1008 to 2015)

Comment: Yes, this is correct!